# Angular ng-repeat not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have had this working in the past, I have moved the site about on localhost and now I can't seem to get `ng-repeat` to display results. Any ideas?

App:

```
var app = angular.module('Search', ['ngResource']);

function seriesListCtrl ($scope, $http) {

// Set the defaults
$scope.url = '/order/series_list';
$scope.products = [];

// On Success add data to the products array
$scope.loadedItems = function (data, status) {
    $scope.products = data;
    $('.Initialloader').hide();
}

// Fetch the URL where the JSON array is
$scope.fetch = function () {
    $('.Initialloader').show();
    $http.get($scope.url).success($scope.loadedItems);
}

// Instantiate the process
$scope.fetch();

}
```

/order/series_list is loading in fine. However, the data doesn't seem to be loading into scope and repeating.

HTML:

```
<div class="order_wrapper" ng-app="Search">
<div ng-controller="seriesListCtrl">

    <div class="well">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-lg-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Description" ng-model="query.series_description"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Part Number/SKU" ng-model="query.product_sku"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion" id="product_list">
        <div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="prod in products | filter:query">
            <div class="accordion-heading order_listing">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 image_container">
                        <img ng-src="{{prod.images_url}}" width="100px">
                    </div>
                    ......... Extra blurb ........
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AnjularJS 1.2.0 - Loading fine

angularjs-resource - Loading fine

So just to confirm: The data is being loaded from /order/series_list with `$scope.fetch`, firebug indicates that the page has been fetched and has content in it. This should then pass data to `$scope.loadedItems` and in turn poop it out into `$scope.products`.

In the html, there is an `ng-repeat` that should then loop through all prods in products. Currently, my `.Initialloader` isn't being hidden and the `ng-repeat` just remains hidden.

I'd really appreciate your help on this - I've been on it for hours and can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want working demo that simulates async loading, please post Json data you load

Answer (score 0):

The `products` list might be empty if you try to print it before load done.

I would use promise factory to handle async call.

So you can write factory like:

```
app.factory('Data', ['$http','$q',  function($http, $q) {

  var data  = $http.get("your URL");    

       var factory = {
            query: function (selectedSubject) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                 deferred.resolve(data);
                  return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
        return factory;
}]);
```

And call from controller:

```
function seriesListCtrl ($scope, Data) {

...

      Data.query()
                    .then(function (result) {
                       $scope.products = data;
                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    });
```

*As a side note*

I strongly recommend to do not make any DOM manipulations/updates in controller. You have directives for that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the filter from the loop?

On a related note, `$('.Initialloader').show();` can be replaced with [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh. Figured it out. I had an issue with my json! So annoying. Thanks so much to everyone who took the time to answer - Very much appreciated.